# Google Social Interaction Events is not reflecting in Google Analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have used the Google Tag Manager along with firebase to track social interaction using Google Analytics, but the data is not being tracked by Google Tag Manager. 
I am getting the following error,

> 2019-09-17 20:31:08.813861+0530 Closet[1125:154048] GoogleTagManager error: Error executing tag 5: TypeError: cannot access property of null.

It is something to do with the Google Tag Manager container file, but I am not sure what is wrong with the container, can anyone point me out with the most possible reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to export the container to another one. This could solve the problem, I read that there was an error in a change to GTM's container definition.
You should download the container file as part of your next build, but installed copies of your application should retrieve an updated container within the next 12 hours.

Comment: What does that mean : Try to export the container to another one ?

Comment: In admin section "Export container". Then create new container. In admin section "Import container".  Then "download" container to insert it into the app.